# A Supporting hyperplane of a Convex body is always closed

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to solve the following problem.(p133 of Taylor's *''introduction to functional analysis''*)

> Let $X$ be a real topological linear space. If $S \subset X,$ a *support* of $S$ is a hyperplane $M$ such that $S$ lies on one side of $M$ and $S \cap M \not = \emptyset$. A closed convex set with a nonempty interior is called a convex body. Show that a support of a convex body is closed.

I think the support does not intersect the interior of $S$. So the support is not dense in $X$, which implies it is closed.

But, I have some trouble with a proof that the support does not intersect the interior of $S$.
Please give me some advice or reference.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Thanks to the comments, I have proved it. I will sketch here.

Suppose $S$ be a neighborhood of zero and $S\subset \{x \in X| f(x) \geq c\}$ for some nonzero linear functional $f.$

For any $x \in \mathrm{int}S$, there exitsts a balanced neiborhoof $U$ of zero such that $x+U\subset S.$ Since $U$ is absorbing and $f$ is not identically zero, there exists $u \in U$ such that $f(u) \not = 0.$ We may assume $f(u) > 0.$ Since $x -u \in x+U \subset S,$ we have $f(x)-f(u)\geq c$, which implies $f(x)>c.$

Comment: Hu? Typo? If S is non-empty and $S \subset X$ then $S \cap X \not = \emptyset$ is a trivial condition.

Comment: Sorry.  $S \cap M \not = \emptyset$ is correct. I have corrected it.

Comment: You need a precise definition of *lying on one side of $M$*. If $M=\{f=c\}$ for a linear functional $f:X\to\mathbb R$ it means $M\subseteq \{f\le c\}$ of $M\subseteq\ \{f\ge c\}$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for your comment. If $S \subset \{f \geq c \}$, then, I think $ \mathrm{int}S \subset \{f  > c \}.$ is it true only on the assumption that $X$ is a real topological linear space? What is missing in my understanding?

Comment: Yes, that's true for real topological vector spaces. You can prove it by using that every open neighbourhood of $0$ (in your case, $S-x$ for an interior point of $S$) is absorbing (which follows from the continuity of the multiplication $\mathbb R\times X\to X$).

Comment: @Jochen Thanks to your comment, I have verified it.  I have added it to the post, please check if you have time.

Comment: Your proof is fine.